# invalid file transfer error on iOS with ionic and cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using the cordova file transfer plugin to download files to users device and it works fines on android. But on ios the file is not able to download and it throws this error in the log

```
File Transfer Error: Invalid server URL http://sampleweb.com/img/1.jpg
```

But this same code i'm using works on android devices

```
downloadImage() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.Transfer.create();
      const audiolocation = `http://sampleweb.com/audio/1.mp3`


    fileTransfer.onProgress((progress) => {
      this.total = progress.total;
      this.loaded = progress.loaded;
      //setInterval(() => {
      this.percentage = Math.round((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100);
      console.log(this.percentage);

    })
      fileTransfer.download(audiolocation, this.storageDirectory+'myapp/'+this.audio_download).then((entry) => {
        const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `Download Succeeded!`,
          subTitle: `Audio has been successfully downloaded`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        console.log(audiolocation)
      }, (error) => {
        const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `Download Failed!`,
          subTitle: `Download Failed. Error code: ${error.code}`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        alertFailure.present();
      });

    });

  }
```